# Cypress - Create group base on JSON file

Tags: javascript, cypress, alert

I wanna create 2 groups (Rose and Sunflower) in App based on the JSON file but the loop only runs 1 time

Here's my code

```
            cy
            .fixture('create-delete-group')
            .then( (gr) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < gr.length; i++) {
                    cy.window().then((win) => {
                        cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns(gr[i].groupNames)
                        groupManaPage.elements.btnCreateGroup().click()
                    })
                    cy.on('window:alert', (str) => {
                        expect(str).to.equal('New group has been created successful!')
                    })

                }

            })
```

Here's json file

```
[
  {
    "groupNames": "Rose",
    "members": [
      "torido11",
      "torido12"
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupNames": "Sunflower",
    "members": "torido13"
  }
]
```

Comment: "the loop only runs 1 time" - how do you know that? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions, and edit this question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Comment: It could be that your JSON data is wrapped in an one array. You can always debug by cy.log()/console.log() your data.

Comment: have you tried using foreach instead of for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **.restore()** the first stub in order to use it again, other than that the code is fine.

```js
cy.fixture('create-delete-group').then(gr => {

  for (let i = 0; i < gr.length; i++) {
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      const stub = cy.stub(win, 'prompt')      // save stub reference
        .returns(gr[i].groupNames)
      groupManaPage.elements.btnCreateGroup().click()

      cy.on('window:alert', (str) => {
        expect(str).to.equal('New group has been created successful!')

        stub.restore()                         // remove stub
      })
    
    })
  }
})
```